# Setting up javax.swing.Timer

Tags: java, user-interface

Ok I'm doing a project and the image is supposed to move around randomly and when the user clicks on the image it's supposed to count how many times the click on it. From there on it keeps moving until they x out. However, I made the mistake of making the image move AFTER they click on it, so when the program starts the image isn't already moving. I need it to move from the beginning of the program.

Attached here because for whatever reason, stack overflow keeps saying I formatted wrong.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

// Zombie class 
public class Zombie {

//declare variables 
private int x;
private int y;

private int size;
private Image image;

//constructor 
public Zombie(int xIn, int yIn, String imagePath) {
    x = xIn;
    y = yIn;
    size = Settings.DEFAULT_SIZE;
    setImage(imagePath);
}

//getter for x
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

//getter for y
public int getY() {
    return y;
}

//setter for x
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

//setter for y
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
  }

  //drawImage method 
  public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, size, size, null);
  }

  //try catch exception, if image isn't found 
  public void setImage(String imagePath) { 
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load image file.");
    }
  }

 }



 public class Settings {

//adjusts the width and height of the creature 
 public static final int WIDTH         = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT        = 300;

    public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE  = 50;

    //image name 
    public static final String ZOMBIE_IMAGE = "zombie.png";
    }

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.util.Random;

class Controller implements MouseListener {

//declares variables 
Zombie zombie;
View view;
private int count = 0;

Controller() { 
    //System.out.println ("Controller()");
} 

public void addZombie(Zombie z){
    //System.out.println("Controller: adding zombie");
    this.zombie = z;
}

public void addView(View v){
    //System.out.println("Controller: adding view");
    this.view = v;
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("Controller sees mouse pressed: acting on Model");
    int prevX = e.getX();
    int prevY = e.getY();

    prevX -= zombie.getX();
    prevY -= zombie.getY();

    if((prevX > 0 && prevX < Settings.DEFAULT_SIZE) &&
            (prevY > 0 && prevY < Settings.DEFAULT_SIZE)) {
        //System.out.println("Got Zombie.");
        Random r = new Random();
        zombie.setX(r.nextInt(view.getWidth() - Settings.DEFAULT_SIZE));
        zombie.setY(r.nextInt(view.getHeight() - Settings.DEFAULT_SIZE));
        ++count;
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

//mouse events 
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    zombie.update(g); 
}
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowStateListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class View implements ActionListener {

private JFrame frame;
Controller controller;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zombie zombie = new Zombie(Settings.WIDTH/2, Settings.HEIGHT/2, Settings.ZOMBIE_IMAGE);
    View view   = new View();

    Controller myController = new Controller();
    myController.addZombie(zombie);
    myController.addView(view);

    view.addController(myController);

    new Timer(500, view).start();

}

private class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        controller.update(g);
        revalidate();
    }
}

private MyPanel panel;

View() {
    //System.out.println("View()"); 

    frame = new JFrame("Catch The Zombie");

    // Create a panel to contain a label, a text box, and a button
    panel = new MyPanel();
    frame.add(panel);    

    frame.setSize(Settings.WIDTH, Settings.HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Zombie was caught " + controller.getCount() + "times");
        }
    });
} 

public void revalidate() {

}

public void addController(Controller controller){
    //System.out.println("View      : adding controller");

    this.controller = controller;
    frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener((MouseListener) controller);
}

public int getWidth() {
    return frame.getWidth();
}

public int getHeight() {
    return frame.getHeight();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    frame.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance of MyPanel inside MyPanel? Why is MyPanel creating an instance of JFrame? I think your idea of a MVC is a little skewed

Comment: You're timer needs to do at least two things, it needs to update the position of the entity and it needs to repaint the window